# NamedNativeQuery not defined in JPA entitty or one of its super classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm currently building an application Quarkus and when I try to use the @NativeNamedQuery my application throws an `PanacheQueryException` saying:

`io.quarkus.panache.common.exception.PanacheQueryException: The named query 'ClassName.findUsingNamedNativeQuery' must be defined on your JPA entity or one of its super classes.`

This is the code that I have:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyClassRepository implements PanacheRepositoryBase<MyClass, UUID> {

    public Optional<MyClass> findUsingNamedNativeQuery(UUID classId){
        return find("#MyClass.findUsingNamedNativeQuery", Parameters.with("classId",classId)).singleResultOptional();
    }
}
```

And this is my @NamedNativeQuery in My Class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_class")
@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = "MyClass.findUsingNamedNativeQuery",
        query = """
                    SELECT mc.* FROM my_class mc
                    WHERE mc.id = :classId
                """,
        resultClass = MyClass.class)
})
public class MyClass{
...
}
```

This is a very strange error that I've never seen while programing in Spring or JakartaEE.
Because it is complaining that the named query is not defined in JPA Entity but it is... I used the same procedures I normally used while working with JakartaEE.

Does anyone know how to use @NamedNativeQuery in Quarkus, if it is really possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (Oct, 2023) it's not supported. [Here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34136) is the issue.
You can call Hibernate API directly like

```java
final var queryString = """
                            SELECT mc.* FROM my_class mc
                            WHERE mc.id = :classId
                        """;

return Panache.getSession()
    .map(session -> session.createNativeQuery(queryString, MyClass.class))
    .map(query -> query.setParameter("classId", id))
    .map(query -> query.setMaxResults(1))
    .map(query -> query.getResultStream().findFirst());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
Although I was not able to do `Panache.getSession()` and add to go with `Panache.getEntityManager()` but in the end worked just fine!
Thank you!

Comment: @renatompf If this solution works for you, please mark this answer as accepted.